# mingw without g++ compiler

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, cross-compiling

i am new to linux and I have the following question:

I am trying to install MINGW in Ubuntu.
I ran the command:

```
   sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

It was installed, and if i put the command gcc it runs ok. The problem is g++ command does not work. I guess it is because i don't have the c++ compiler (as I read in similar questions in stackoverflow).
I read too that you can use the next command:

```
   mingw-get install g++
```

but i don't have the executable program for this command.

My question is, how can I install that executable? or is there another way to update my mingw so I can use the g++ compiler?

Hope I have explained myself correctly. Thank you for any help I receive.

Comment: what "command"? what "interpreter"? g++ is a compiler, not an interpreter. Are you trying to cross-compile form Linux to Windows? If not, why do you need anything else than the normal pre-installed GCC toolchain?

Comment: sorry, i think i didn't explain myself right, it is due to english is not my native  language mixed with my ignorance in linux. g++ is the compiler for c++, right?. When i said "interpreter" i meant what is needed to be installed for linux recognizing the command mingw-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mingw-get` is a windows specific package manager, it is not needed when you use a native linux package manager such as APT.

Installing package `mingw-w64` depends on package `g++-mingw-w64`, which depends on `g++-mingw-w64-i686` and `g++-mingw-w64-x86-64`.

These packages install the mingw cross compilers as

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++-win32
```

Older versions of mingw cross compiler shipped `/usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-c++`, which is replaced by `i686-w64-mingw32-c++-win32`

You can usually use this toolchain in a project by running `./configure CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-c++-win32` or `make CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-c++-win32`

Note: the above description is correct for the most recent toolchain in Debian unstable. It may need some minor tweaking for older systems.